# upload local files to make them accessible in a build step when deploying with Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

How can I get local files and folders into cloud build?

You can create volumes but can you create a volume from a local folder and access its files in a build step?

I have a cloud build template in a local folder. I want to be able to run cloud build locally and have those local files get imported into the cloud build environment/steps. it is not triggered from a repo I'm just running the cloud build command locally.

I am also calling cloud build from deployment manager- not seeing any of the imported files under the handler folder:

```
imports:
  - path: handlers/**

resources:
  - name: build-something
    action: gcp-types/cloudbuild-v1:cloudbuild.projects.builds.create
    metadata:
      runtimePolicy:
        - UPDATE_ALWAYS
        #- UPDATE_ON_CHANGE
    properties:
      steps:
        - name: 'ubuntu'
          args: ['bash', '-c', 'echo "====================================="']
        - name: 'ubuntu'
          args: ['bash', '-c', 'pwd']
        - name: 'ubuntu'
          args: ['bash', '-c', 'ls', '-laR', '/']
      timeout: 120s
```

Comment: When you say "I want to be able to run Cloud Build locally", do you mean using the local builder (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-debug-locally)? Or do you simply run the 'gcloud builds submit' command?

Comment: Use COPY command to add all files and directories to your docker.
Cloud build cannot understand the volume.

Comment: not using a local builder. I want to get my local files into cloud builders workspace- so I want it to pull in my local files somehow

Answer (score 5):

When you run a Cloud Build in a directory, Cloud Build do this:

- Takes ALL the file and subdirectory from your current directory
- Excludes the files present in the `.gitignore` file or in the `.cloudignore`file if exists
- Makes a TAR file
- Send the tar to Cloud Build environment

Cloud Build service extracts the tar file in `/workspace` directory and run the `cloudbuild.yaml` file. You can check the content of your `/workspace` by running this step

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: [ '-c', 'ls -la']
```

Comment: Good tip for the bash command to see the directory contents. Add `-R` to make it recursive for subdirectories.

Comment: updated my post to be more specific. Im not trigger this off a webhook/repo im starting it locally through deployment manager